# PHP only increments once

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

The value for $i in the code below is always 2.  It seems it increments to the first time, but only that time.  Any thoughts?

```
 foreach ($records as $row){

    $i = 1;
    $i++

    if ($i % 2 != 0){
        $trClass = 'odd';               
    }else{
        $trClass = 'even';
    }

    echo '<tr class="' . $trClass . '"><td>' . 
        anchor("admin/delete/$row->id", 'delete') . '</td><td>' . 
        anchor("admin/edit/$row->id", 'Edit') . '</td>';

    foreach ($row as $key => $value){
        echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: ...also: You're incrementing `$i` twice... watch that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're reassigning it to `1` every time through the loop. Initialize it outside the loop instead.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($records as $row){
    /*
     ...
    */

    $i++;
}
```

Also I see that you're incrementing both at the beginning of the loop and at the end. I assume you only want to do it once (probably keep only the one at the end; remove the one at the beginning).

Comment: Yep.  Not using my eyes very well today.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a logical error in that it declares $i in every iteration of the loop.

This is what you do:

declare $i = 1 in every iteration and then increment that $i.

so in every iteration, you get $i = 2 all the time.

declare $i = 1 outside the foreach loop and increment $i just once like so:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($records as $row){

        if ($i % 2 != 0){
           $trClass = 'odd';               
        }else{
           $trClass = 'even';
        }

        echo '<tr class="' . $trClass . '"><td>' . anchor("admin/delete/$row->id", 'delete') . '</td>
            <td>' . anchor("admin/edit/$row->id", 'Edit') . '</td>';

                 foreach ($row as $key => $value){
                     echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
                 }
         echo '</tr>';
         $i++;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

start it this way

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($records as $row){
    $i++;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

please put `$i = 1;` before `foreach`